# Validate concrete exception details in JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

To validate exception message I can use `ExpectedMessage` object but what if I want to validate concreate exception and it's details? For example I have exception class `TerribleWindException` which has some additional methods like `getWindSpeed()` and in junit test method I want to check the `getWindSpeed()` result. Look at this example:

```
// pseudo implementation

public class TerribleWindException extends Exception {

    private Integer windSpeed = 0;

    public TerribleWindException(final Integer windSpeed) {
        this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
    }

}

public class WalkService {

    private Integer windSpeed = 0;

    public WalkService(final Integer windSpeed) {
        this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
    }

    public void goForAWalk() throws TerribleWindException {
        if  (windSpeed>10) {
            throw new TerribleWindException(windSpeed);
        }
    }

}

// test

public class WalkServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void testGoForAWalkWhenSpeedIsToPowerfulShouldThrowTerribleWindException throws TerribleWindException {
        WalkService ws = new WalkService(100);
        goForAWalk(); // this will throw TerribleWindException. The only way to check it's exception details is to use try {} catch() {} ?
    }

}
```

The only way to check exception details is to use try {} catch() {} ?

Answer (score 6):

You could use JUnit's [ExpectedException rule](http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) together with Hamcrest matchers.

```
public class WalkServiceTest {
  @Rule
  public final ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

  @Test
  public void testGoForAWalkWhenSpeedIsToPowerfulShouldThrowTerribleWindException throws TerribleWindException {
    WalkService ws = new WalkService(100);
    thrown.expect(TerribleWindException.class);
    thrown.expect(Matchers.hasProperty("windSpeed", Matchers.equalTo("expected speed")));
    ws.goForAWalk(); // this will throw TerribleWindException. The only way to check it's exception details is to use try {} catch() {} ?
  }
}
```

If you're using Java 8 then you can use the [Vallado library](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/vallado/) together with Hamcrest.

```
public class WalkServiceTest {
  @Test
  public void testGoForAWalkWhenSpeedIsToPowerfulShouldThrowTerribleWindException throws TerribleWindException {
    WalkService ws = new WalkService(100);
    when(() -> ws.goForAWalk())
      .thenA(TerribleWindException.class)
      .that(hasProperty("windSpeed", equalTo("expected speed")))
      .isThrown();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For such case i suggest you to use [catch-exception](https://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/) library from Google, code sample (from their homepage):

```
import static com.googlecode.catchexception.CatchException.*;
import static com.googlecode.catchexception.apis.CatchExceptionBdd.*;

// given: an empty list
List myList = new ArrayList();

// when: we try to get the first element of the list
when(myList).get(1);

// then: we expect an IndexOutOfBoundsException
then(caughtException())
        .isInstanceOf(IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
        .hasMessage("Index: 1, Size: 0") 
        .hasNoCause();
```

See also [catch-exception AssertJ api](http://javadoc.catch-exception.googlecode.com/hg/index.html?com/googlecode/catchexception/apis/CatchExceptionAssertJ.html) if above example is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use an `@Test(expected=Exception.class)` annotation to test the class of the exception thrown, but to test the details you will need to catch and interrogate the exception yourself.

Don't forget to `fail()` if the exception isn't thrown. e.g.

```
try {
   operation();
   fail("Expected an exception");
}
catch (MyExpectedException e) {

   // assertions...
}
```

Comment: How can we do both  @Test(expected=Exception.class) and catch and interrogate the exception ourself at the same time? I think we should not try to add logic to our tests, adding both seems like step in that direction.

Comment: You can't, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java 8 there is actually a more flexible way to achieve what you want, which uses Lambdas.
The following steps are necessary:

- Create a getter for the `windSpeed`-attribute of your Exception
- Create a functional interface for a lambda which takes no parameters and returns nothing and which might throw an exception, like this (Runnable is not suitable, because it does not throw an exception and Callable has a return value):

  ```
  @FunctionalInterface
  public interface TestCommand {
      public void exec() throws Exception;
  }
  ```
- Create your own assertion for exceptions, like this:

  ```
  public <T extends Exception> void myAssertThrows(TestCommand testAction,
      Predicate<T> p) {
      try {
          testAction.exec();
          fail("must throw exception");
      } catch (Exception exception) {
          assertTrue(p.test((T) exception));
      }
  }
  ```
- Use it in a test:

  ```
  @Test
  public void testGoForAWalkWhenSpeedIsToPowerfulShouldThrowTerribleWindException(){
      WalkService ws = new WalkService(10);
      myAssertThrows(() -> {
          ws.goForAWalk();
      }, (TerribleWindException e) -> e.getWindSpeed() == 100);
  }
  ```

So how does it work? `ws.goForAWalk();` is packed into a lambda of type `TestCommand` so it is not immediately executed. It is the first parameter of `myAssertThrows` and executed in this method. The second parameter is a predicate on Exception, which is simply a lambda which takes one exception as parameter, returns a boolean and can be used to check properties of the exception, which is thrown. The assert method uses the well-known try-catch-style.

You could actually also use the assert method in Java 7, but the call would be less readable, because it would need anonymous classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Junit's Rules [Junit Rules](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules), which includes an ExpectedException rule, which can be used to also test messages of exceptions.

EDIT:

If you implemented TerribleWindException the following way:

```
public class TerribleWindException extends Exception {

    private Integer windSpeed = 0;

    public TerribleWindException(final Integer windSpeed) {
        // use Exception constructor, which passes a message
        super("windSpeed: " + windSpeed);
        this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
    }
}
```

You could achieve what you want using this test code:

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void shouldTestExceptionMessage() throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

    thrown.expect(TerribleWindException .class);
    thrown.expectMessage("windSpeed: 100"); 
    WalkService ws = new WalkService(100);
    ws.goForAWalk(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one makes more sense than my previous answer, but I am not editing my previous answer because it serves most of the use cases.

The ExpectedException rule allows you to specify, within your test, what exception you are expecting and even what the exception message is

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;

    import org.junit.Rule;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;

    public class CloudTest {

      @Rule
      public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

      @Test
      public void testExpectedException() {
        exception.expect(CustomException.class);
        exception.expectMessage(containsString('Invalid cloud type'));
        new Cloud("Rainy","With thunder", "big");
      }
    }
```

Comment: As I wrote I want to check specific method output. Let's imagine that `CustomException` stores some specific value like `customValue`. How to validate this value using `ExpectedException`? You can check message because it's attribute of `Exception` class which is extended by `CustomException`.

Comment: Why cant your CustomException class extend "ExpectedException" class? Now assuming your CustomException class has a specific value like 'customvalue' you can end up checking that as well.

Answer (score -1):

I often use a scenario like the following:

```
@Test
public void testGoForAWalkWhenSpeedIsToPowerfulShouldThrowTerribleWindException throws TerribleWindException {
    WalkService ws = new WalkService(100);
    try {
        goForAWalk();
        fail();
    catch(TerribleWindException twe) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No you can catch specific exception by using the following template

```
@Test(expected= TerribleWindException.class)
```

Comment: As I wrote I want to check details of the exception. Using your solution I can't do this.